Ubuntu Machine not booting up
Arm64 machine with ubuntu 24.04  installed won't boot up. It is an arm8.0 .It doesn't have any display so not really sure where during the boot up its getting stuck. We usually connect through the machine using ssh . Tried rebooting but its still not loading the OS.
Connected to the console through serial port  and tried rebooting the machine . attached the screenshot for the console.enter image description here

are you sure you have the right version? The version for ARM is only at 24.04 download ARM server
